# how to expand package-created heatmap for aesthetics

Tags: r, heatmap

I have installed a package (CellCODE) where a function (called "getAllSPVs") has been defined that allows me to specify, as one of the arguments
that the output be in a plot format:

```
getAllSPVs(data, plot=TRUE)
```

However the function has been defined in a way that the legend covers a portion of the graph and the writing both in the legend and on the axes is too small to read:

[image]

I have tried to manually make re-define the function so that I can move the legend  off of the plot and make the writing more legible. The result of my modifications is as follows:

[image]

but I only managed to move the legend off of the graph to a certain extent and it is still partially covering the dendogram. I also changed the size of the writing on the Y-axis (how is specified below- still working on this such that it doesn't jumbled). The arrows indicate the space that I would like the graph to perforate. But no matter what I do with the margins the heat map just won't expand.

Below is the code that I modified to make the adjustments that I achieved so far (please pay particular attention to the parts that I have commented as #####IMPORTANT):

```
 getAllSPVs<-function (data, plot = F) #output in form of plot when specified in command is set to TRUE
  {

  (.......)
  if (plot) {
    parlast = par(mar=c(1,1,1,1),no.readonly = T) ####IMPORTANT inserted the par argument here.
    datatmp = rbind(data[rownames(dataTag), ], t(SPVs))##### Don't Understand
    datatmp = resid(datatmp, grp)                          # any of this
    labGenes = c(apply(dataTag, 1, function(x) {           # but it might be
        which(x > 0)[1]                                    # important for
    }), rep(ncol(dataTag) + 1, ncol(SPVs)))################# expanding the heatmap

    mycol = c(rainbow(ncol(dataTag))[sample(ncol(dataTag))], 
              "black")
    corplot(datatmp, usecordist = T, ColSideColors = mycol[labGenes], 
            labRow = c(rep("", nrow(dataTag)), colnames(dataTag)), 
            density.info = "none", cexRow = 2, dendrogram = "column", #changed cexRow to value of '2'
            key = F)
    par(mar=c(0,0,0,0)) ##### IMPORTANT:changed from the original par(mfg = c(1, par()$mfcol[2]))
    legend("topright", fill = mycol, legend = colnames(dataTag), #specifying it to be top-right (or any other corners doesn't stop it from covering the graph data
           ncol = 1, xpd = NA, cex = 0.7, inset = 0) # here I changed the 'cex' argument to 0.7 from 1
    par(parlast)
}
colnames(SPVs) = colnames(dataTag)
SPVs
}
```

I have tried playing with the margins of the image as much as possible to expand the heat map such that everything isn't so cluttered...

Overall, my question is how do I re-define the function so that the the plot output of the heat map will be expanded and everything won't be so cluttered....

Can anyone recommend a particular margin ratio such that the white space marked in the above picture can be filled... Or do I need to do something else to get the heat map to expand?

Maybe I'm missing something fundamental and it's not to do with the margins at all...